# Concept works apparently in class but using hooks the value is not set in state hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**the value is not set in state hooks**

`

```
> const Post = (props) => {
>     
>     const [selectedFile, setselectedFile] = React.useState([]);
>     
>     const upload=event=>{
> 
>     setselectedFile(selectedFile,event.target.files[0]);
> 
>     }
>     
>     }`
```

Comment: setselectedFile(event.target.files[0]); toy only need to put the file no need to put the old state

Comment: do you want to maintain a list of file or only the current file

Answer (score 1):

you only need to set the current state.

If you want to maintain a list of selected files then do the following

```
setselectedFile([...selectedFile,event.target.files[0]]);
```

If you only want to maintain the current file then do this

```
setselectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
```

Comment: Already tried but it shows the null value value is not settt thats the problem

Comment: then are you sure that there is a file in the files collection.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fix this issue..
Problem is here

const [selectedFile, setselectedFile] = React.useState([]); this is incorrect..

```
 const [selectedFile, setselectedFile] = React.useState(""); Correct Finally this can fix this issuee
```